# How do I restore a Windows 7 System Image to a OS X Lion Boot Camp partition?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, restore

I just updated the hard drive in my MacBook Pro. I decided to also take the opportunity to upgrade it to Lion. I previously had Boot Camp under Snow Leopard. I created a new Boot Camp partition and went through Windows 7 installation. Now, I am trying to restore my previous Windows 7 system image. Windows restore seems to insist on wanting to format the entire drive though. Clearly I don't want to do this.

Is there any way to restore the image back into the Boot Camp partition?

I am willing to hack around the recovery console if necessary.

Comment: Oh, and forgot to mention. I did a trial restore on the old hard drive of the system image, and it worked just fine. The windows recovery environment did not have the option selected to format the entire drive, and indeed it just restored over the c: drive, leaving the osx partition alone.

Answer (score 2):

[Winclone](http://twocanoes.com/software.php?software=1) might be a good solution.

Winclone allows you to image a Bootcamp partition and migrate it to a new Mac, or in this case a freshly installed OS on a new HD. Here's their tutorial: http://twocanoes.com/asset.php?id=9